# Selecting an autocomplete list does not save the word fully when using ajax to save

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I built an autocomplete list of cities using a mysql query. Typing in the input field correctly initiates the search and builds the selectable city list. The problem is that the city name in full does not get saved, only the characters typed when using .on('change'... I tried other mouse events such as mouseover, mousemove, mouseout, mouseenter, mouseleave - and they require the user to first select the item from the list, move out, then swipe the cursor over the input a second time to actually trigger the save of the selected city name. The html looks like:

```
<input type="text" onmouseover="this.focus();" class="saveCity" name="pob_city" member_id="<?php echo $member_id; ?>" value="<?php echo $pob_city; ?>" placeholder="City" id="pob_city" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> $("#pob_city").coolautosuggest({ url:"tools/autosuggest/query_cities.php?chars=" }); </script>
```

The saveCityCountry javascript:

```
$(document).on('mouseout','.saveCity',function()
{
  var DATA=$(this).val();
  var n =remove_whitespaces(DATA);
  var MEMBER_ID=$(this).attr('member_id');
  $("#Results").html( "" );
  if(n  !=''){
  var dataString = 'pob_city='+ n +'&member_id='+MEMBER_ID;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "saveData.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html)
      {
        $("#Results").html( html );
      }
    });
  }
})
```

You can see a demo at: http://dottedi.us/misc/ajaxsave/

The other thing that is slightly bothersome is that with ordinary input fields such as first or last name, the on change event only triggers when you click somewhere else on the page, thus the placebo "Save" button.

Update: I cleaned up the code in my example splitting off City from Country and updated the post to reference saveCity. This will not affect the result, just a bit easier to follow.

Inside the http://dottedi.us/misc/ajaxsave/tools/autosuggest/js/ folder are two javascript files that might be relevant, jquery.coolautosuggest.js and jquery.coolfieldset.js. On line 46 of jquery.coolautosuggest.js I see `success:function(data){`.  You want me to place "**source: data, autoFocus: true, delay: 0, minLength: 0, select: response, response: response**" somewhere in here? Please make it clear where and with the right syntax, semicolin, etc.

In the codeblock you added, I assume that I change the HTML adding the **,response** and the function response just gets placed somewhere within my saveData.js. Once this is right, do I go back to change as opposed to mouseout or mouseover?

Comment: looks like it works to me `Q: update demo set pob_country='Alger' where member_id = 4373` i only typed a then selected one

Answer (score 0):

include response function in your autocomplete call, where you can assign the selected value to hidden field, This will allow you to retain full text.

I assume you are getting array of cities, store each city in an array in a key called "city" and return it.

Define one hidden field say "selected_city".

Inside your coolautosuggest success function place this code

source: data,
autoFocus: true,
delay: 0,
minLength: 0,
select: response,
response: response

```
$("#pob_city").coolautosuggest({ url:"tools/autosuggest/query_cities.php?chars=" },response);

function response(){
   if (typeof ui.content != "undefined" && ui.content.length === 1) {
      city= ui.content[0].city;
   }
   else if (typeof ui.item != "undefined" && ui.item.label.length > 0) {
      city= ui.item.label;
   }
   if (label.length > 0 || index.length > 0) {
      $("#selected_city").val(city);
      // this value you can use to display
   }
}
```

before doing this please change the below function on jquery.coolautosuggest.js at line 120

if(me.submitOnSelect==true){                            $("form").has(me.textField).submit();
}

to

if(me.submitOnSelect==true){
$("#pob_city").val($(this).find(".suggestion_title").text());                                                       $("form").has(me.textField).submit();
}

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the pointers but I didn't write the autosuggest script (found via google) and I'm not adept at JavaScript, so this will take some additional instruction.  To my original post I just added my full update comment.

Comment: Thx. I modifield the html and added the response script as you instructed, then I made the change you indicated on line 120. However, it is not clear to me where to add the **source: date, autoFocus...** line and how it should be formated.

Comment: is it working without adding that bit of code?? dont put response function now, just add code at line 120 and try to run it. i guess that one line should solve your problem.

Comment: No - not working.  I edited the html for City in index.php and deleted the **",response"** from the autosuggest line. Now it does not even save characters as you type (which was wrong anyway). As is, after you make a city selection (select city/release) you have to swipe the cursor over the input field to get it to save the full city name - sort of back to square one.

Comment: do you have any further suggestions how to make this work or can you contact me privately for assistance?